# Are there any plans to support edit-and-continue of XAML in future VS versions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

It would make life so much easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is <strike>completely</strike> impossible.

When you run a WPF app, the XAML is parsed in the constructor into a visual tree, which is then displayed as a form.

Edit & Continue would mean re-creating the visual tree, which would break any code in the form.

Comment: I wouldn't say "completely impossible". They could take a diff between the old and new XAML, then apply that diff to the current visual tree. It wouldn't be perfect, probably limited to mostly attributes, but even that would be useful.

Comment: @Jonathan: It would be very difficult to do and probably wouldn't work reliably. Remember that the visual tree can be changed in code, and that there is no connection between an element and the XAML that it (may have been) parsed from.

Comment: Starting with something limited but useful: 1. Only allow changing attributes on named elements. 2. Lookup those elements using reflection on the form's properties. 3. Assign the new values to the properties that match the attributes. I'm sure you could implement this as a function Fixup(oldXaml, newXaml, openForms) in an hour.

Comment: yeah, completely impossible seems like a challenge to me! ;)

Comment: It is no more impossible than edit-and-continue in good old WinForms InitializeComponent. Just break elsewhere in the program and edit your code. It will be re-loaded the next time the form is created. Is it impossible for XAML exactly in this way, at least?

Comment: I recall this impossible thing used to be said (by some SO giants) about lambda expression during debug too till recent; and now we have it working in VS2015. It is only a matter of time and feedback before we have edit & continue for XAML too, at least as much as Jonathan has described. :)

Answer (score 2):

Now this feature is available from visual studio 2015 update 2.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164926.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/06/ui-development-made-easier-with-xaml-edit-continue/

Comment: VS2017 not VS2015

Answer (score 1):

XAML Edit and Continue is now possible in VS 2015 for UWP apps. This should be available with the "Windows 10 Anniversary Update".

More info and a demo of the upcoming feature can be viewed here https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B853

Comment: Just wanted to make the comment that this feature also supports WPF, not just UWP. We continue to invest into this feature in Visual Studio 2019 and welcome all feedback